# How do I take an integer and put every number leading up to it in an array?

Tags: arrays, c

I am not very good at English and was not sure how to phrase this question but I want to take an integer and make an array like this if the integer is 10:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

I've tried:

```
int main()
{
    int array_finished = 0;
    int array_add = 1;
    int array[10] = {0};
    while(array[10] != 10){
        array[array_finished] = array_add;
        array_finished = array_finished + 1;
        array_add = array_add + 1;
        printf("looped");
    }

    printf("%d", array);
}
```

But it just prints a bunch of random numbers after 9 "looped" appear.

Comment: The `array[10]` element is out-of-bounds for a variable declared as `int array[10];`. The indexes start at **zero** and end at `n-1`. Looks like you actually want `while (array_finished != 10) {`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { array[i] = i + 1; }`

Comment: In your own words, when you write `while(array[10] != 10){`, what do you think should be the result of `array[10]`? Where do you expect that value to come from? What do you think are the valid indices for the array? Is `10` such a valid index? (Hint: when `array_add` is `10`, what will `array_finished` be? According to that logic, where do you expect the `10` value to be written - what index?)

Comment: And `printf("%d", array);` is the same as `printf("%d", &array[0]);`, i.e. it prints a pointer to the first element. You need another loop to print each and every element of the array in turn. As in `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { printf("%d ", array[i]); } printf("\n");`

Comment: You already started with some `printf()`-style debugging, keep going. Add interesting values to your loop output, like the contents of some loop variables... -- Oh, and you give the address of the array, that is the address of its first element, to the final `printf()` but tell it to print a single decimal. That cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an array with size `n`, its indexes will be from `0` to `n-1`. You create an array with the size `10`, its indexes will be from `0` to `9`. Trying to access `array[10]` will result in out-of-bounds.

Second, by `(array[10] != 10)` you mean to compare the eleventh element of `array` with `10`, which is probably not what you want. You probably meant to loop over `array`.

Finally, `printf("%d", array);` print the address of the array but tell it to print a single decimal. You probably meant to print all the elements in `array`

```c
int main()
{
    int array_add = 1;
    int array[10] = {0};
    for(int array_finished = 0; array_finished < 10; ++array_finished){ // using a for loop instead of a while loop
        array[array_finished] = array_add;
        ++array_add;
        printf("%d\n", array[array_finished]); // print after all the calculations  
    }

}
```

Comment: The code doesnt compile for some reason and says: error: 'array_finished' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: @RandomCodeEnjoyer Sorry that was a typo, I forgot to add the `{` in the `for` loop. Now it should work as expected

Comment: Note: More C idiomatic to change `array_finished <= 9` --> `array_finished < 10`.